# Separate animation for string update with setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

In `JavaScript` I have:

```
var strArray = ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3"];
```

and random string `update()` loaded function:

```
function update() {
  var randStr= Math.floor(Math.random()*strArray.length);
  s1.innerHTML = strArray[randStr];
}
setInterval(update, 6000);
```

in html:

```
 <div id="s1" class="str1"></div>
```

where I use `webkit` to animate letter spacing:

```
.str1{
  -webkit-animation:compression 6s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes compression {
  from 
  {
    letter-spacing: 1px;  
  } 
  to 
  {  
    letter-spacing: 0px;
  }
}
```

this animation naturally works with page loading, but I'm trying to figure out, how it is possible create animation with update of `setInterval(update, 6000);` for each new random string appearance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing animation name will do a trick to restart the animation.

```js
const s1 = document.querySelector(".str1");
let strArray = ["Text1", "Text2", "Text3"];

function update() {
  var randStr = Math.floor(Math.random() * strArray.length);
  s1.innerHTML = strArray[randStr];
  s1.style.animationName = "anything";
  
  setTimeout(() => { // setTimeout needed
    s1.style.animationName = "compression";
  }, 10);
}
setInterval(update, 2000);
```

```css
.str1 {
  animation: compression 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes compression {
  from {
    letter-spacing: 15px;
  }
  to {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="s1" class="str1">Text</div>
```

Comment: Hello, yes, it is exactly what I was trying to do